# SP2013 - <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Tags: 2013, powershell, administration, backup, restore

I successfully restored a backup from another farm a few of weeks ago using restore-spsite.  I had to delete that site collection, now I want to restore it again with that same backup file. The 2 farms I have tried the restore on have the Nov 2014 CU and SP1.  I'm not sure what version the farm that this came from is on but the restore worked with the same CU levels a few weeks ago like I said.

I run:

```
PS C:\Users\useraccount> Restore-SPSite -Identity http://sp2013:4444/sites/site1
-Path c:\files\backup.bak -Force
```

.. and I get this error:

```
Restore-SPSite : <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-SPSite -Identity http://sp2013:4444/sites/site1 -Path
c:\files\backup ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:
   SPCmdletRestoreSite) [Restore-SPSite], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreS
   ite
```

This directory is valid.

In the ULS logs I see:

```
 12/12/2014 13:18:41.97     PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           Backup and Restore              7944    Information Starting restore of site collection: 'http://sp2013:4444/sites/site1', requested by: company\useraccount, source: \\ashare\sharedocs\customerbackups\site1\backup.bak   5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.00  PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        aeayb   Medium      SecurityTokenServiceSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustChannelContract' Action: 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:47ed22a4-72d5-4e23-ba4c-9c7a4d1a2b3d' 5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.00  w3wp.exe (0x29A8)                           0x2B5C  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        aeax9   Medium      SecurityTokenServiceReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://sp2013.qa.company.local:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:47ed22a4-72d5-4e23-ba4c-9c7a4d1a2b3d'   5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.00  w3wp.exe (0x29A8)                           0x2B5C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (ExecuteSecurityTokenServiceOperationServer). Parent No    5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.02  w3wp.exe (0x29A8)                           0x2B5C  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           af3y9   Medium      STS Call Claims Windows: Successfully requested sign-in claim identity for user 'company\useraccount'.  5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.02  w3wp.exe (0x29A8)                           0x2B5C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteSecurityTokenServiceOperationServer). Execution Time=13.1675    5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.05  PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           Upgrade                         ajyw6   High        12/12/2014 13:18:42.05 powershell (0x35B4) 0x3DF4 SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPHierarchyManager ajyw6 DEBUG [SPTree Value=SPSite Url=http://sp2013:4444/sites/site1] added to dependency cache by lookup 5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9    5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.07  PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ki7k    High        Could not deserialize site from \\ashare\sharedocs\customerbackups\site1\backup.bak . Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Schema version of backup 15.0.4631.1000 does not match current schema version 15.0.4569.1000     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Restore(String filename, Boolean isADMode, Boolean& readOnlyMode, Boolean& hadWriteLock)    5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.07  PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e11    High        Deleting the site at http://sp2013:4444/sites/site1 and not deleting AD accounts.   5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.08  PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         88z7    Medium      SPRequest: Logging result 0x2fc69680 from reInit    5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.08  PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e2s    Medium      Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070003  5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.08  PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         72k4    Medium      <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>  5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.08  PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8kh7    High        <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>  5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.08  PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aix9j   High        SPRequest.GetSiteFlags: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-1078081533-1957994488-682003330-8169, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=http://sp2013:4444/sites/site1   5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.08  PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>, StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Delete(SPSiteDeleteFlags flags)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Restore(String filename, Boolean isADMode, Boolean& readOnlyMode, Boolean& hadWriteLock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Restore(String strSiteUrl, String strFilename, Boolean bOverwrite, Boolean bGradualDelete, Boolean hostHeaderAsSiteName, Boolean preserveSiteId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreSite.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()     at Sys... 5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.08* PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...tem.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)     at Sys...  5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.08* PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...tem.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)     at System.Management.Automation.DlrScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)     at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.DoCompleteCore(CommandProcessorBase commandRequestingUpstreamCommandsToStop)     at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()     at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc()     at ...  5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.08* PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium      ...System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()    5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.10  PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           PowerShell                      6tf2    High        System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetSiteFlags(String bstrUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetSiteFlags(String bstrUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Delete(SPSiteDeleteFlags flags)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Restore(String filename, Boolean isADMode, Boolean& readOnlyMode, Boolean& hadWriteLock)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSiteCollection.Restore(String strSiteUrl, String strFilename, Boolean bOverwrite, Boolean bGradualDelete, Boolean hostHeaderAsSiteName, Boolean preserveSiteId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreSite.InternalProcessRecord()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord... 5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
    12/12/2014 13:18:42.10* PowerShell.exe (0x35B4)                     0x3DF4  SharePoint Foundation           PowerShell                      6tf2    High        ...()   5c3edbe2-c18a-414b-8650-87b9eecbd7e9
```

The first directory listed in the logs is a network path.. however, after this attempt, I copied the bak file to a local drive with no difference in the end result.

I've read this [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76804/what-is-causing-this-error-restore-spsite-nativehr0x80070003-nativehrn) and this [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82886/i-cant-delete-or-restore-a-site-collection-or-repair-database), but nothing applies to my situation.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try Get-SPDeletedSite and see if it returns any results

Comment: When I run that, it shows all my other site collections.  The one that I was restoring over is not there anymore.  In the logs, it says it deletes it during the restore-spsite process.. which I think is normal if I'm restoring over it.

Comment: Reason I raised that point was that if you look at your log trace the error is actually when it is trying to delete as part of the restore process System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>, StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite.Delete(SPSiteDeleteFlags flags)

Comment: their is one time job Gradual Delete, try to manully run that for the web app where you restoring the site collection

Comment: any update on this issue ? Im facing the same on sp2013 15 0 4727 1000